# How do I allow JNLP launched software access sockets?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

One of the bigger software packages I maintain is deployed via JNLP.  Lately we're running into a lot of issues with it.  I had a previous Stackoverflow question due to it not allowing MD5 hashes to be done.  Another major issue is that sockets get blocked sometimes.  Some of our manual code is fine, some that looks otherwise identical is intermittent, and some of the included libraris (EWS for updating our Exchange calendars) fails everytime when launched via JNLP (but works every time if the JAR is run off a local copy).

How can I fix the security so that everything works via JNLP just like it was a local copy?

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: Already done, checks out fine.  Good comment though for others that might end up here looking for answers.

Comment: Latest version of Java breaks JNLP parameters now.  We're in the process of moving off of JNLP as fast as we can now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of JNLP have changed parameter passing restrictions for security reasons.  I was able to eventually get everything required in place and migrate back to JNLP.